# Problem removing iSCSI target from ESXi 4.0 host

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi

I am new when it comes to working with ESXi 4.0 and connecting to iSCSI devices.

I have a "Lacie 5big Network 2" drive which is setup with RAID 5 and and 3.6TB of available space.  Using instructions from " http://www.techhead.co.uk/vmware-esxi-4-0-vsphere-connecting-to-an-iscsi-storage-target " I was able to add the device to the ESXi host.  Unfortunately it was only allowing me to use 1TB out of the 3TB which was dedicated to iSCSI.  I have no idea why.  This is another problem that I'm facing.

So I went ahead and removed the iSCSI drive from the ESXi host but I'm now running into problems.  I am unable to reconfigure the Lacie iSCSI drive size because it displays the following message: "iSCSI not available while a computer is connected to the target"

Since I've undone all the changes from within VMware vSphere Client, what else is left for me to do?  Is there a file within ESXi that I could edit to clear this issue?

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help me resolve this issue.  If I'm not clear about anything that I've mentioned here please let me know and I'll clarify with more information.

Comment: You'll need to restart ESXi to completely remove the iSCSI connection to the Lacie.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're only able to use 1TB but I suspect it's due to ESX/i's 2TB-per-LUN limit - basically you can't have a single VMFS extent larger than 2TB nor can it address a larger than 2TB LUN properly - carve your iSCSI LUNs into <2TB and try that again.

As for the problem you face, well if ESXi doesn't 'see' it then you're safe to do what you like from the LaCie perspective - i.e. reboot it as it appears to still be locked. This may just be an incompatibility issue, no LaCie storage products are on the VMWare Hardware Compatibility List I'm afraid.

Comment: I restarted the Lacie the day after I posted this question online, but before reading your answer.  In any case, it worked just fine.  The LaCie may not be on the HCL list but it definitely works as an iSCSI target.  Thanks for replying to my question.